# what are the initial values of pointers in "array of pointers"?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Before putting my question, I want to quote "Expert C Programming" [Page :276, last paragraph]:

"The beauty of Illiffe vector data structre is that it allows arbitrary  arrays of pointers to strings to be passed to functions, but only **arrays of pointers**, and only pointers to strings.
This is because both strings and **pointers** have the convention of an explicit out-of-bound value(NUL and **NULL**, respectively) that can be used as an end marker."

So, What I understood from above text is that if there is an array of pointers they have explicit out-of-bound value like NULL.( Correct me , if I'm wrong...)

So, it left me wondering what are the default values of an array of pointers(thinking that an array of pointers would have last pointer as NULL). Tried below code-snippets and result was very different.

```
    int *x[2];
    printf("%p %p",x[0],x[1]);
```

Output is: (nil) 0x400410

```
    int *x[3];
    printf("%p %p %p",x[0],x[1],x[2]);
```

Output is: 0xf0b2ff 0x400680 (nil)

```
    int *x[4];
    printf("%p %p %p %p", x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]);
```

Output is: (nil)  0x4003db  0x7fffe48e4776   0x4006c5

So, with the above outputs , it is clear that there is an explicit Out-of-Bound (nil) value assigned to one of the pointers(one pointer is NIL), but is it truly the end-marker? No.

Is it one of those "Implementation defined" things of C-language?

I'm using a GCC compiler(4.6.3) on a Ubuntu machine.

Comment: You horribly misunderstood the author. He says you can *easily* mark the end of an array of pointers. e.g. `char *a[] = {"a", "b", NULL};` But still *you* have to mark (not done automatically) ;-)

Comment: got it...damn those (nil) values... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misreading the quotation from "Expert C Programming." The key phrase there is the following:

```
This is because both strings and pointers have the *convention* of an explicit 
out-of-bound value (NUL and NULL, respectively).
```

It is possible and even *conventional* to have an array of strings such that the last pointer is set to `NULL`. This can allow one to iterate over the array quite easily without knowing exactly how many elements there are in the array:

```
char* dwarves[] = { "Dopey",
                "Grumpy",
                "Sleepy",
                "Happy",
                "Sneezy",
                "Bashful",
                "Doc",
                NULL 
                };
```

But you have to explicitly set the last pointer to `NULL`. Such structures are useful because they allow elegant code. So if you want to print or otherwise manipulate the array, you don't need to worry about how many strings are in it, as the `NULL` pointer will signal the end:

```
for (char** pWalk = dwarves; *pWalk; pWalk++)
    printf ("%s\n", *pWalk);
```

The beauty of this particular type of ragged-array structure is that strings by definition have a built-in `NUL` terminator, and the array of pointers is terminated with the `NULL`, so the endpoints of both dimensions are known. However, the `NULL` as the last pointer in the array is not something that's built into the language. It has to be explicitly set. Failing to do so would be the equivalent of declaring an array of `char` but not terminating it with a `NUL`:

```
char myString[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' }    // No NUL termination
```

Just as you would have to know how many characters there are in this array if you want to manipulate it in any useful way, without the `NULL` at the end of the array of pointers, manipulating it would be more difficult.

That's really all that Peter van der Linden is saying in the paragraph you quoted about Illiffe data structures.

Comment: though other answers above are also correct..i would go with your answer as accepted..wanted to upvote others but can't do that bcoz of not enough "reputation". :)

Comment: You have enough "reputation" now; 15 is needed. I agree the other answers deserve upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it one of those "Implementation defined" things of C-language?

No, that's not implementation-defined - it's plain "undefined". The same is true for arrays of all types: the values that you see in them are undefined until explicitly initialized.

> What I understood from above text is that if there is an array of pointers they have explicit out-of-bound value like `NULL`.

The author wanted to say that there is a value (specifically, `NULL` value) that can be used to mark a "no value" in an array of pointer. The author did not mean to imply that such a no-value marker would be placed into an array of pointers by default.

Answer (score 4):

An array, or any object, with *automatic storage duration* (i.e., any object defined within a function body without the `static` keyword) has no default initial value unless you specify one. Its initial value is garbage, and you *must not* access that value before assigning something to it.

An object with *static storage duration* (i.e., any object defined outside any function and/or with the `static` keyword) is initialized to zero, with the meaning of "zero" (0 for integers, 0.0 for floating-point, null for pointers) applied recursively to subobjects.

You can use an *initializer* to ensure that a pointer object is set to a null pointer, or to whatever value you like:

```
int *x[2] = { NULL, NULL };
```

or, more simply:

```
int *x[2] = { 0 }; /* sets first element to 0, which is converted to a null
                      pointer; other elements are implicitly set to null
                      pointers as well */
```

Comment: Even objects with static storage duration needs care wrt *markers*. e.g. `char *a[2] = {"a", "b"};`

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement in C that any local variable should have any 'default' value. So, when the compiler reserves two (or three) memory locations, the initial value is whatever that these memory locations contained before - there will not be any default initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your array was declared at file scope (outside of any function) or with the `static` keyword, the array contents will not be initialized; each element will contain some random bit pattern that may or may not correspond to a valid address.

If your array was declared at file scope or with the `static` keyword, then each element would be implicitly initialized to `NULL`.  Note that attempting to dereference a NULL pointer results in undefined behavior, so you will want to check that your pointer isn't NULL before doing something with it.

A null pointer represents a well-defined "nowhere", guaranteed to compare unequal to any valid memory address.  Note that there is a null pointer *constant*<sup>1</sup> and a null pointer *value*<sup>2</sup>, and the two are not necessarily the same.  In your source code, the macro `NULL` is set to the null pointer *constant*.  During translation, each occurence of `NULL` in your source code is replaced with the real null pointer value.

There are invalid pointer values other than NULL; it's just that NULL is well-defined and works the same everywhere.

---

<sup>1.  Any 0-valued integral expression, as used in a pointer context.  Could be a naked `0`, or `(void *) 0`, or something else that evaluates to 0.

2.  Value used by the platform to represent a null pointer, which does not have to be 0.</sup>